# CSS/JS Asset Visualizer

Tags: javascript, css, sitemap, assets

Is there a utility out there that will generate a "sitemap" for page resources? Over the years our site has accumulated a bunch of duplicate copies of various JS and CSS assets and I'd love a way to plug in our site and have it generate a list of what gets called where so we can start cleaning up. I just started going through manually- it's totally possible for me to do it by hand, but it's going to take a while and I figure something like this has to already exist.

Can anyone make a recommendation?